# How to prevent my Image from scaling down?

Tags: itext, itext7

I am using iText 7.2.1.

I create two images in the following code. They are two rectangles, created from `PdfFormXObject`. The first is 100 x 100, and the second is 1000 x 100. They have the same stroke width. I have `SetAutoScale(false)` for both images.

```
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;

namespace iTextTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var writer = new PdfWriter("test.pdf");
            var pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
            var doc = new Document(pdfdoc);

            // 100 x 100 rectangle
            var rect1 = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
            var xobj1 = new PdfFormXObject(rect1);
            var canvas1 = new PdfCanvas(xobj1, pdfdoc);
            canvas1.SetStrokeColor(ColorConstants.RED);
            canvas1.SetLineWidth(5);
            canvas1.Rectangle(rect1);
            canvas1.Stroke();
            var img1 = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(xobj1).SetAutoScale(false);
            doc.Add(img1);

            // 1000 x 100 rectangle
            var rect2 = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 100);
            var xobj2 = new PdfFormXObject(rect2);
            var canvas2 = new PdfCanvas(xobj2, pdfdoc);
            canvas2.SetStrokeColor(ColorConstants.RED);
            canvas2.SetLineWidth(5);
            canvas2.Rectangle(rect2);
            canvas2.Stroke();
            var img2 = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(xobj2).SetAutoScale(false);
            doc.Add(img2);


            doc.Close();
            pdfdoc.Close();
            writer.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

When I add them into the document, apparently, the first image is of the original size, but the second image is scaled down.

[image]

I want the images to not scale at all even there isn't enough space. How to do this?

Comment: Apparently 1000×100 does not fit on the page. Thus, iText has the choice of scaling it or rejecting it. You would have preferred rejection?

Comment: Thanks for your information. So `SetAutoScale` does not work here. I wanted to make a page with a very wide outside margin. Most texts and images do not exceed page margin, but occasionally wide images are allowed to exceed. Maybe the only way is to use a blank placeholder image to keep the space and place that wide image at absolute position.